# How to get PermissionSet oldMap value and compare with new one in after update trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, permission-sets, trigger-oldmap

I need to figure out if values in PermissionSet for current user are changed in trigger, i'm thinking about using oldMap but i can't figure it out.

Maybe this code will explain what i'm trying to do:

```
    for (User u : trigger.New)
    {
        List<PermissionSetAssignment> lstOldPermSet = Trigger.oldMap.get(u.id).PermissionSetAssignments;
        List<PermissionSetAssignment> lstNewPermSet = // get PermissionSetAssignments via soql query

        if(lstOldPermSet != lstNewPermSet)
        {

// code goes in here

        }

    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I am not sure but do you want to compare all the values and all the permissionSet attached to a user ?

Comment: Try posting entire code

Comment: PermissionsSetAssignment do not allow trigger manipulation. Are you using iTriggers?

Comment: @MerabtiIbrahim I need to run certain code when user get's or loses PermissionSetAssignment.

Comment: @SaumyaGaikwad What are iTriggers? Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @NikolaNaumovski This will help you http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/trigger-pattern-for-tidy-streamlined-bulkified-triggers

Answer (score 1):

The after update trigger on `User` object will fire only when you will update any field of the `User` object.

If you will add or remove the`PermissionSets`, the trigger on User object will not fire.